# In this case padding-right can be 0

Tags: css

I'm quite new to CSS so I just testing and experimenting to see how it works

In this example we have the selector `.box h3` that has `padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;`,
so `padding-right` here is `10px`. But actually, this `padding-right` can be `0` without
cause any difference in the layout.

Also in the selector `.box ul` we have `padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;`, so we can set 
`padding-right: 0` without cause any change in layout.

What is the best practice to use when for example setting `padding-right` in this example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Chapter 5: Indestructible Boxes</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body 
        {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }

        a 
        { 
            color: #00458B; 
        }

        .box 
        {
            width: 273px;
        }

        .box h3 
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;
            font-size: 130%;
            color: #333;
            background:#e3e3e3;
        }

        .box ul 
        {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;
             list-style: none;
         }

         .box ul li
         { 
             margin:0 0 6px;
             padding:0;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
    <h3>Gifts and Special Offers</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/purchase/">Purchase Gift Subscription</a></li>
    <li><a href="/redeem/">Redeem Gift Subscription</a></li>
    <li><a href="/view/">View Purchase History</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He's saying that there's no difference if the right padding is 0 or 10px because there's nothing to the right of the element, so he's asking what's the better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding-left will be sufficient and padding-right will not be needed for most of the cases, since .box has only width: 273px;

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to keep in the padding-right:10px.  that way if you ever give the box a background-color, you'll be able to see that the content does not hit the edge of the box (even if you make the links longer, or if the user increases the font size).

Answer (score 1):

you should keep it just in case, you dont want to have to edit code later on.

anyway `padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;` could be `padding: 14px 10px;` saves space, and `padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;` can also be `padding: 6px 10px 4px;` [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).